# Generic table to display property data for various objects

Tags: vb.net, oop, datagridview

I have a lot of different objects in the VB.Net code I inherited. A list of each type of object gets displayed in table dedicated for that object type, with each row representing an object, and the columns showing the object's property data.

For example, let's say I have the following class objects: Man, Building, Tree, Tool.  Then the user can view a table containing all the Man objects (and ***some*** but not all of the associated properties), a table containing all the building objects, a table of all the tree objects, and so forth.

Right now, each object table is on its own dedicated UI. So every time I create a new object type, I have to copy the table UI and change the code to reflect which properties of the new object type are displayed in which columns.  Not ideal, because the tables all perform the same basic functions, just on different objects. Users can edit property data in the table, load a more detailed window for an individual object showing all the property data, delete individual objects, etc.

I'm asking for advice on how to switch from using a dedicated UI for each list of objects to having a single generic UI capable of loading different properties, depending on which object type is being loaded to the table? Is there a clean way to assign the individual columns to the various properties without using a massive "select case" block? Again, I'm working with a rather large set of objects in VB.Net, which I display in a datagridview table.

Comment: I think you might want to learn about [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which does exactly what you want, if I undesrtood you correctly.

Comment: Could you check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) also ? It explains how to bind a DataGridView to a datasource, and the columns will be generated automatically...